# Is there a way to dynamically import a directory of SVGs as a base icon component in Vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, svg, vuejs3, vite

I am using Vue 3 with Vite. I have a directory and sub-directories with SVG files. Let's say something like `/icons/plus.svg`, `/icons/minus.svg`, `/icons/status/alert.svg`. I want to have a base icon component, optionally but ideally with TypeScript support to provide safety and IntelliSense completion. Each SVG file name is name for that icon as a prop, like this:

`<BaseIcon name="plus" />`

I want this for ease of use, avoiding pasting SVG content into my component markup and to be able to pass in currentColor as the fill which doesn't work with `<img>` tag

How can something like this be achieved? Currently, I can make a base icon component work by  converting SVG files into vue files by wrapping them in `<template>` tag, then import all of them inside the BaseIcon component and accept a dynamic name prop. This however does not allow type-safety or IntelliSense, and I need to manually create the vue file and update my imports with the new file. I want the imports from the directory to the component to be auto-updated.

I would love some help on this. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/load-file/load-file.github.io loads an external (svg) file and injects it in the DOM